# How can I evaluate text response as code in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to fetch a response from a server. I'm essentially scraping data from a chart to make a better chart. Anyway, the response comes back as javascript variables

```
'var x = [["data","like"this"],["and","like","this"]]'
```

When I use a plain .js file I can eval the response and then return x and it works.

However that same code when running inside of a React Class doesn't work.

Anyone know why or if somehow that variable is attaching to a different scope? I'm under the impression react doesn't run in strict mode so I think eval should work as far as setting variables.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    fetch("url-to-scrape")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();//only way I can view the response
      })
      .then(data => {
        eval(data) //should set variable x
        console.log(x)// this is where I will setState
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Smarter Chart</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Problem with eval is scope. You are probably better off parsing the file with code.

Comment: Can you add the code snipet?

Comment: I've added the react implementation. when I run the getData function outside of react it works fine.

Comment: is x `undefined` when you log it?

Comment: correct, I'm curious if it gets defined but in a different scope.

Comment: Not guaranteed, but see if a normal function instead of an arrow function will catch it

Comment: Ah, yes I believe that will work. I'm only working with part of my code right now. I will verify this evening and let you know to write an answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue why my response is coming back as Javascript variables. Either way, I figured out the way to parse this data in React.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("url-to-scrape")
      .then(response => { //ReadableStream hiding response
        return response.text(); //Convert ReadableStream to text
      })
      .then(data => {
        var data_from_x = eval(data + "; x;"); //eval x and return it
        this.setState({data: data_from_x });
      })
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>welcome to the app</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I eval the response text which is a string `'var x = data'` In the eval I then add  `+ '; x;'` which calls that variables data within the eval. I set that data to a variable and then return it or in my case, setState. I now have a good amount of data for a fully customized chart.

I situations where I get multiple variables I can just pull all of them out the same way by name.

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect to use x, there seems to be a guaranteed structure to the data. Assuming this to be a single variable declaration, you can extract this into json by grabbing a substring immediately after the equal sign. While this code needs to be changed if there is more than one variable in the response it is both safe to use and void of scope issues in contrast to eval.

```js
const response = 'var x = [["data","like", "this"],["and","like","this"]]'

const output = JSON.parse(response.substring(response.indexOf('=') + 1))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: unfortunately I will have some responses that have  `var a = data; var b = data; var c = data;`